# Installer won't install dishwasher due to "old" stop valve

Tags: plumbing, valve, dishwasher, installation

We just ordered a new Bosch dishwasher from Home Depot, including third-party installation.  The installer they sent looked under the sink and said that because our stop valve is too old, that he could not do the installation "through the company".  I said that I could hop over to the hardware store to get a new valve, but he would not allow me to do that.  He said that he could do it off the books if I gave him $100.

Instead of accepting this offer, I rescheduled the installation for next week-- I will buy the $10 valve and put it on myself.  However, I don't see what the problem is with the valve that we have (visible in the center of the picture).  Is the type of valve that we have simply not used any more?  If there is an issue, I'd like to fix it correctly before another installer comes.

[image: Under the sink]

Comment: maybe the tech wanted to make some extra cash .... i see no reason why the service would not be available "on the books" ... the only problem with those valves is that the rubber washer disintegrates after some years and pieces of rubber end up downstream ... get a 1/4 turn ball valve

Comment: I think your "extra cash" idea has merit. HD has some pretty "limited" installers. Our dishwasher plumbing is identical to the photo and nothing was said about the valve.

Comment: On top of rescheduling, report the tech to HD.

Comment: Not valve related, but: the tech sent to install my new washing machine refused to do so because of an existing (~1 year old) water hose, then tried to sell me a replacement hose for ~100€ (5x retail price). I sent them home and did the installation myself, but I suppose not everyone is willing/able to do that.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the replies.  I got a new 1/4 turn ball valve for $12 and I will put it on.

Comment: Did the installer attempt to turn off the valve and have the valve fail to actually turn off the water? Or, did they just *look at it* and say "no, can't do it"? If it's the former, then that valve does need to be replaced, which could easily be a larger job than what the installer is contracted for by Home Depot. If it's the latter (look, but no test), then you need to find out what's imposing that requirement. Is it Home Depot and the contract with the installer? Is it a code requirement in your area? Is it just the installer wanting some extra cash?

Comment: He just looked.  I assume it was contractual.  The old valve did have a little bit of corrosion on it (which I was unable to see until it was removed).

Comment: "I can do it off the books for $100" is a clear red flag for fraud.

Comment: @TylerH - I expect it to be a contractual issue rather than a fraud issue. He's a third-party contracted by Home Depot to do straight dishwasher installations. In order to keep costs down, it's likely that Home Depot has limited the scope of his work (and any associated warranties and insurance) to simply "install the dishwasher". He's probably also not allowed to take on work from HD customers without going through them. So installing as a cash job is about the only way he can do it. $100 seems steep for a $12 part, but it probably covers time to go pick up the part, the part and install.

Comment: @DWGKNZ Then the installer shouldn't refer to it as an "off the books" job but as a separate job independent of the Home Depot installation (and thus not covered by any HD warranty). "Off the books" has one meaning: tax fraud.

Comment: Definitely, I would generally expect that to be the case (along with terms such as cash, under the table, and perk job) but in this case, it may be for a different reason, ie. keeping the job out of Home Depot's sight as they may have an open book clause within the contract. Either way, it's the contractor's responsibility to report his income for tax purposes.

Comment: Recently had a similar situation with a new oven. Had it delivered from Lowes. My wife _thought_ she purchased the pig-tail to plug it in, but it didn't get put on the order. The installers offered to sell me one they have in the truck, but we had to pay cash. Claimed that if they break into the "emergency spares" kit on the truck, _their_ employer takes it from their paycheck, so they have to get cash from us up front. Ended up going to the store myself to get a pig-tail.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Capsule summary of the comments:

- Your old valve should probably be replaced with a new quarter turn ball valve version. Those old valves wear out and break your heart when it really matters.
- Report the installer to Home Depot. There's a strange, outside chance that they are limited in what they are allowed to do, but I sincerely doubt it.

Comment: "quarter turn" = ball valve.  And yes, ball valves are better.

Comment: Disagree.  I think "including installation" does not include updating your plumbing.  In fact, you're lucky if the gorillas they send out would know how to update your plumbing. I think OP is lucky the installer recognized the need and offered to do it and didn't just install the thing poorly in order to check the box and go home.

Comment: Disagree with point 2. This is perfectly par for the course for Home Depot, they paid enough claims and lawsuits over water leaks. Another known example is Home Depot will not install any washing machine without brand new flex hoses.

Comment: @user71659 What about "he could do it off the books if I gave him $100"? Is that worth reporting to HD?

Answer (score 10):

You *should* update this valve now that you are in there installing a new dishwasher.

The dishwasher purchase, "with installation" correctly does *not* include updating your plumbing.

It is *extremely easy* to replace this valve yourself.  The pipe is exposed and in good shape and the old valve uses a compression fitting.  Buy a Sharkbite quarter turn dishwasher valve (straight, not 90 degrees) and a Sharkbite pipe reamer.  Unscrew the old one, shove on the new one and you're done.  5 minutes.

[image]

If you want someone else to do it, I'd accept the offer from this guy.  It's reasonable and you don't have to find someone else and coordinate.

Comment: Disagree. It's a jacked up price from a profiteering "installer" who "would do it "off the books."" And there's no need to faff about with a sharkbite where there's a perfectly good compression fitting on the pipe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this comment.   The compression fitting is integral to the old valve being replaced.  How can it be reused?  The ferrule can't be reused either.  Maybe you could reuse the nut by why?  You could buy a compression valve if you're not a Sharkbite fan but it will come with all new parts.  I don't get the comment.  And I would expect an appliance retailer to be clear that replacing customers' plumbing shall not be done as part of a free install.  If some well-meaning installer does it and it goes wrong, the customer could, and SHOULD, expect the retailer to make good.

Comment: Is it clear to all that the installer works for the appliance retailer not for OP?  And  probably is subject to a massively lawyered up contract designed mainly to protect that retailer?

Comment: The compression fitting is a bog standard part. You unscrew the nut from the old valve and remove it. The nut and ferrule already on the pipe screw into any compression fitting of the same size - you just remove the nut and (uncrimped) ferrule from the new one. You most certainly can re-use them, if you're not so daft as to try and remove them from the pipe they are installed on.

Comment: Just to add to @Ecnerwal comment above... if some gorilla with 18" wrenches mangled the heck out of the ferrule, then it'll be pretty clear when you re-use it that you aren't going to be watertight. At that point, just nip the copper back a bit and install everything new. But I'll always reuse a ferrule in good condition.

Comment: My hunch is: installer has specific rules of what they are to do/not do as part of a standard installation, won't go over because their boss (or themselves if they are a one-man shop) knows they will not get 0.01 extra from HD for any extra work. Offering to do it as a side job off the books, on the spot, is actually quite reasonable. The only issue is the $ amount. If this were a regular plumber (who would likely charge more overall than the package price from HD) then adding that valve might be $50 to cover time & materials. $100 is overpriced in comparison. But to get a plumber out *only*

Comment: for that one little task is likely to cost $100 when he walks through the door. So $100 is perfectly reasonable in comparison to that. A **lot** of people will not attempt a valve replacement themselves, and some others will decide that unless they enjoy trips to HD (I do, but well...) that the time it takes to get the part and install it is not worth it and they would rather just hand over an extra $100 and be done.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I take "off the books" to mean "without warranty and insurance", which should be included in the $100 you pay for the proper plumber. For me that would be one reason to avoid such an offer (the other reason being that where I live working "off the books" would be tax fraud).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Those are definitely possible issues. I am taking "off the books" here to mean "HD doesn't know about it". Which raises *other* issues, but if (as may be the case) HD simply has no process for contracted installers to do anything beyond a standard simple installation, that really doesn't bother me. To the insurance, etc. issues, there is one more concern: licensing as a plumber. It is quite possible that some of the installers have basic business/handyman/etc. licenses (which varies a lot by jurisdiction) but **not** an actual plumbing license. If that's the case then...

Comment: legally they can't replace the valve themselves because they're not "plumbers". You, as homeowner, generally can make such repairs yourself. If that's the case, then liability is a real issue. On the other hand, if the installer is a licensed plumber then the only "off the books" issue is taxes, and that is, at least where I am, the installer's concern and not the homeowner's concern.

Answer (score 2):

Let me take this from the value proposition angle (I am assuming you own none of these)

- A [scoring tube cutter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-5-8-in-Junior-Tube-Cutter-80-511-111/304384093) is about $15.
- A simple metal file is $10 or less (or you can buy a de-burr/reamer tool for more than that).
- A Sharkbite 3/8" ball valve itself (just shove it on) is maybe $12 (and it's as close to goof-proof plumbing as you can get)
- A water shutoff key is less than $10 in most cases

So about $50 in hardware. Takes about 10-15 mins to turn your water off, cut the pipe, deburr it, shove the Sharkbite on and turn the water back on. By the time you add all that up, the average homeowner is probably not going to spend that time and money when you can pay some guy who has it on his truck and all the tools to do it right there. Add in the convenience factor, and $100 isn't exactly *unreasonable*, but you could spend that money to have the tools yourself to replace, say, the other valve under your sink. Or the rest of the valves in your house. And you come out ahead from not paying the installer some $90 to do it. This is a DIY site and... well, we're gonna tell you to buy the tools and do it yourself.

The reason HD likely has a policy like that is these older mutli-turn stop valves do wear out over time. My house is some 40+ years old and I've been steadily doing this over time because some of them just stopped working properly (some needed a wrench to get them to cut off). I recently replaced my kitchen sink and the gaskets inside disintegrated when I tried to turn them off. It's worth your time to buy the tools and replace both valves there (and any others you can reach).

Comment: Why sharkbite? Why not just re-use the existing compression fitting?

Comment: @GlenYates The OP said their installer said it had to be a quarter-turn ball-valve or no deal. Possibly a scam, but there are legit reasons to balk at the crank-turns like this.

Comment: I was questioning the recommendation to replace the valve with a sharkbite version, not questioning whether the valve should be replaced with quarter-turn ball valve - it should.

Comment: Sharkbites are typically less hassle for not a lot more money (as of this writing a Sharkbite is only $1 more than a comparable compression ball valve). For someone who has not done plumbing before, the extra cost is worth it.

Comment: Except in this instance, sharkbites are way more hassle! To use a sharkbite, you have to cut off the existing connection then file the cut smooth. To replace the old compression valve with a new quarter turn compression valve, you simply unscrew the old one and screw the new one in. You don't need any tools but a wrench.

Comment: Two wrenches. One to hold the valve, one to turn the nut.

Comment: I suspect the people suggesting SharkBite fittings are used to sweated on shut off valves, as you correctly noted, in this case, they are compression fittings and no pipe cutting is needed to replace in kind (with the ball valve type).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Bosch dishwashwer.  HD 3rd party installer told me the same thing, except that he wasn’t willing to do anything “off the books”.

The issue in MY case is that the thread on the existing valve is different from the “more modern” compression valves.  While everything looks perfectly fine, the thread on the “water from the outside male connection” isn’t “a reduction thread” while the fitting on the dishwasher line from that fitting TO the dishwasher IS “reduction thread”.

I bought a new valve/fitting from Ace, will turn off the water and replace the existing valve with the new one, which SHOULD allow the dishwasher line to connect without me having to jump through hoops otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It is a modern income source for Home Depot and other vendors. I recently purchased a washer and dryer from Home Depot and they would not install them without all new connection equipment ( hoses, wire, ducts, etc). You could consider it profit or covering the cost of install labor. Not all a bad idea as I can imagine some of the equipment is old and worth updating. I had previously installed all my own stuff including furnaces, roofing and central AC , but I am older and tired now, so not a bad deal.